# Can't find Self-Service Registration in OKTA

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, okta

I am attempting to locate the Self-Service Registration option within the Okta dashboard. Previously, it was located under the Directory tab, however, I am unable to locate it now. There may have been an update to the dashboard. What is the new location of the Self-Service Registration option?

[image]